# How to send server action form data to API request - Next.js

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I am trying to send the form data to a fetch request via Server actions in Next.js 14. The `formData.get('code')` doesn't seem to be making it through and I just get a generic response from the OpenAI API. Ideally the user will send some code in the input and it will send back a little description of what it does and language, etc.

Here is my code below. Is there also a way to display the api response to the page?

```
export default async function CodeLangTest(){

  async function getCode(formData) {
    'use server'

    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.URL}/api/codelang`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData.get('code')),
      cache: 'no-store',
    });
  
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }
  
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data.choices)
    //return data.choices;

  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Select a language</h1>
      <form action={getCode}>
        <input name="code" type="text" />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are not providing a key for formData.get("code") while sending JSON data. try JSON.stringify({ code: formData.get("code") }))